# Modular architecture "multiplatform"

Tags: web-services, architecture, software-design

First of all, I'm sorry if the title is a little misleading but I can't find better words to describe it.

In the near future, I will work on a brand new web application. The web application by itself is not the problem, but I already know what the clients want. Today they want a basic website for their needs, but tomorrow they'll also have smart phones and tablets and they will ask for a mobile application. The easiest way is obviously to create a "good CSS" that will be usable on every platform (which is already planned).
However, I think it will also be a good choice to be able to offer a native experience on mobile platform (android, apple, windows) and this is where I face something I truly don't know.

I'm not really a mobile developer but I'm pretty sure I can connect my application to a database (which is the one used by the web application). This way I can redo everything I've done on the web application and both could work together. It will most likely work pretty well, however this means I have to duplicate my logic code to both the web application and the mobile app (for every platform !). To be this is a big nope, in the short term : no problem but quickly the project will be unmaintainable.

The idea would be to create all on one side, and use this logic on the web application / mobile applications. The main benefit is that whether I use the mobile or the web application, I will strictly call the same program, the development will also be easier for every platform because we'll only need to display and design.

Ad you may have understood, my idea is to create a webservices application. The web application will requests everything via webservices, and it goes also for mobile platforms.
However, I've never seen it somewhere and I'm not even sure this is a really good idea. Can you confirm ?

If this is really a good idea, how can I handle the authentication & sessions of the users ? If I want to use something else than a login/pwd to authenticate ( Kerberos, CAS, LDAP, X509 ...), can it we handled on the "webservices" side.
Once the user has validated his login/pwd, how can I handle requests to protected webservices, i.e update a user (should I use tickets inside every requests ?)

Do you know some opensources applications that works as I want to do so that I can understand how they done that ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the best approach is use a REST API, you need to code once your business logic and reuse at any platform you want just writing the client that can understand the REST API. Basically decoupling the services from the view.
Consider use in your web application any javascript fwk capable of do some HTTP request, from the android/ios devices there are some useful libraries that can also call the REST endpoints.

Authentication can be done but OAuth, SSO or another mechanism using the different frameworks depending in the language you want to develop.
Session will be handled by the application server in which you deploy your solution.

**Answering OP comment.**
When I said build a REST API is basically have it deployed in a back end solution in an application server (something that support http calls), by this I meant have it isolated from the clients codes, usually deployed in another server. There are some examples such as spring-mvc, node.js, .net, essentially the only responsibility of these deployed services will be handle all the calls to get the result from your business logic.

Good example of enterprise and paid solutions can be found [here](http://waracle.net/how-to-choose-the-right-backend-as-a-service-baas-platform/).
To get more knowledge about the backend concept you might find useful [this](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/54145/i-dont-really-understand-backend-serverside-when-it-comes-to-web-development) and [this](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/38905/how-to-explain-to-my-client-the-difference-between-front-end-and-back-end).  About the examples it really depends on the tec hnology that you use, but I think cakephp have some plugins to handle the REST API [calls](http://www.slideshare.net/neilcrookes/designing-cakephp-plugins-for-consuming-apis).

Comment: Thank you for your answer, this is what I thought. I wasn't thinking about using javascript on the web application but more likely curl on the server side (we use cakephp at work). The main idea is to create one web application with an API. This API will be used inside the application itself (am I clear ?). By application server, you mean to handle SSO&sessions at the API side or for every platform (web, mobile,...). Do you know some examples of applications that works like that so I can have a better understanding ? Thank you.

Comment: Hi Ryuu answers in my response